# How do I get a Pinterest API app approval?

Tags: api, pinterest

maybe this is not a code question, but we really do not know where to ask... We already submitted several requests to Pinterest support, but still waiting for our app to be approved, after several weeks... Essentially, we didn't get any useful answer from Pinterest... Our client is pressing us a lot, and also we need to bill..

So, has any of you had the same issue? How did you eventually solve?

Comment: We have the same issue, Our application is still in pending since 2019. Had few discussions with their team but haven't got any good response.

Comment: Were you able to get a response from them?

Comment: No. A shame. Can't really get the thing.